# Using both onboard video and Nvidia video card

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I have a 4 monitor setup. 2 monitors are connected to my onboard intel video and 2 are connected to my Nvidia video card. When I reach the login screen for Ubuntu I can see all 4 monitors however as soon as I enter my password, the 2 monitors connected to my onboard video go black.

Any idea how to fix this? I'm new to linux / ubuntu.

Thanks!